# How can i create a card view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

I am adding a card View in a simple activity, as i write it's code, Android studio start showing an error "Rendering Problem" 
How can i come over it ? Here i'm attaching my code..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.sj.digitalapplications1.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Digital Application Android Team"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post here the sufficient log,error/screenshot can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency in your build.gradle.

```
dependencies {       
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'    
}
```

Or Right click on Project-> Go to module settings->Open Dependencies Tab->click on plus sign on right corner->select library dependency->select cardview library

Comment: HI, thanks for your help but i couldn't find this in my android studio 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/smartbro_perc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

You have missed these thing, please add the below code.

1. In your xml

   ```
   xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto Add it
   ```
2. In build.gradle (Module app)

   ```
   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0' // this version or above version ++
   ```

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'

Use this as a dependency in your build.gradle file. This might work in Android Studio 1.5.1.

P.S: I assume that you are using SDK Version >=21